# C# Состояние консольного приложения

Tags: c#

Приветствую.

```
        private void cmd()
    {
        Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {               
            FileName = filename,
            Arguments = arguments,
            UseShellExecute = false, // false для скрытия
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        });
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; // запускать приложение в фоновом режиме (Hidden)
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();
        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TSharkOutputHandler);
        p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TSharkOutputHandler);           
    }
```

Запускаю консольное приложение на в фоне. По окончанию работы окно консольного приложение закрывается.

Мне нужно контролировать состояние окна. Знать что консольное приложение открыто.

Comment: Не правильно мыслите, вам не "знать что открыто" надо, а "ждать, пока не завершиться". Делается это через `p.WaitForExit();`, а еще лучше `p.WaitForExitAsync();` и метод сделать асинхронной задачей, чтоб не вешать UI (если есть).

Comment: Пробовал добавлять p.WaitForExit(); ставил ниже. Приложение переставало корректно работать. Т.к. консоль скрыта я не вижу работает она или нет. Охото сделать надпись "работаем ... "

Comment: Я вам ведь выше сказал на этот счет) Вызываете `WaitForExitAsync()` асинхронно (`async/await`), будет "корректно работать", ну а "работаем...", перед вызовом этого ожидания пишите куда надо.